# Anyway we could know the real geolocation of a person to ensure that they don't hack GPS

Tags: geolocation, gps

Because anyone could fake their geolocation lat/long number to the app by various means. Are there any cheap and practical solution or service we could ensure that they have really stay in the same place as the geolocation they sent?

Maybe approximation from IP Address or something like that. I just think about geolocation game like Pokemon GO that should require people to really travel to specific location

Comment: you can you ip adress to get the location , but if they use vpn the ipadress will change .what do you do then you cant get exact location

Comment: Hey you can use geolocation api from google , it works fine even  if users is using vpn

Comment: @newlearner But then what if they use a fake request data?